# This object does not have an attribute named yaml structures

Tags: terraform

I want to construct my organisation structure in one yaml file for github provider to manage teams, members, some teams contain subelements like subteams, some don't, for loop errors with "This object does not have an attribute named" when structure in yaml is not the same, I tried playing with lookup(), contains(), if() but I am just starting using terraform so maybe you could help me how I could achieve this?

```
# cat locals.tf

locals {

  teams = yamldecode(file("teams.yaml"))["teams"]
  teams_flatten = flatten([
    for team in local.teams :
    {
      team_name   = team.name
      description = lookup(team, "description", "")
      privacy     = lookup(team, "privacy", "closed")
    }
  ])

  subteams_flatten = flatten([
    for team in local.teams : [
      for subteam in team.subteams : {
        team_name    = team.name
        subteam_name = subteam.name
        description  = lookup(subteam, "description", "")
        privacy      = lookup(subteam, "privacy", "closed")
      }
    ]
  ])
}

│   on locals.tf line 16, in locals:
│   16:       for subteam in team.subteams : {
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "subteams".

# cat teams.yaml
---
teams:
  # Parent team
  - name: Engineering
    # This team has sub-teams
    subteams:
      - name: access
        members:
          - member: alex
            role: maintainer
          - member: bob
            role: maintainer
      - name: payments
        members:
          - member: alice
            role: maintainer

  # Parent team
  - name: Marketing
    # This team does not have any sub-teams
    members:
      - member: bob
        role: maintainer
      - member: alex
        role: maintainer


# cat teams.tf

resource "github_team" "teams" {

  for_each = {
    for team in local.teams_flatten : team.team_name => team
  }

  name        = each.value.team_name
  description = each.value.description
  privacy     = each.value.privacy
}

resource "github_team" "subteams" {
  depends_on = [github_team.teams]
  for_each = {
    for subteam in local.subteams_flatten : subteam.subteam_name => subteam
  }

  name           = each.value.subteam_name
  parent_team_id = lookup(github_team.teams, each.value.team_name)["id"]
  description    = each.value.description
  privacy        = each.value.privacy
}
```

Comment: Generally this is how lambda iterators function in almost every language. If you want to iterate over a specific nested key, then that key must exist within the structure of each iterator.

Comment: yeah, but but but :) sometimes you might want to try make things work when elements exist, sometimes not, so trying to figure out how to make it work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with raw human-edited files like this where the structure is not necessarily consistent, it can sometimes help to explicitly normalize the data structure first as a separate step, and then to use the more consistent data structure elsewhere. That then keeps the dense conditional code isolated in one place and so hopefully makes the rest of the module easier to read.

For example:

```
locals {
  teams_raw = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/teams.yaml"))["teams"]

  teams = {
    for team_raw in local.teams_raw : tostring(team_raw.name) => {
      name = tostring(team_raw.name)
      subteams = tomap({
        for subteam_raw in try(team_raw.subteams, []) :
        tostring(subteam_raw.name) => {
          name = tostring(subteam_raw.name)
          members = tomap({
            for member_raw in subteam_raw.members :
            tostring(member_raw.member) => {
              name = tostring(member_raw.member)
              role = tostring(member_raw.role)
            }
          })
        }
      })
      members = tomap({
        for member_raw in try(team_raw.members, []) :
        tostring(member_raw.member) => {
          name = tostring(member_raw.member)
          role = tostring(member_raw.role)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The two main relevant characteristics of the `local.teams` definition above are:

- It uses `try` in a couple places to provide a fallback value for when a particular key isn't available. That means that the resulting data structure will always have an attribute of that type but it might refer to an empty map, which is easier to deal with than an attribute that may not exist at all.
- It uses `tomap` and `tostring` liberally to assert the expected types for each of the attributes. This will therefore allow Terraform to raise an error early if the given value isn't suitable for one of those constraints, and ensures that Terraform can infer a suitable static type for this data structure which you can rely on elsewhere.

With this new normalized data structure you can refer to `members` and `subteams` on all of the elements, and know that it'll always be set but might be set to an empty map.

Comment: `│ Error: Invalid reference`
`│   on locals.tf line 5, in locals:`
`│    5:     for team_raw in teams_raw : tostring(team_raw.name) => {`

`│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.`

I tried changing it to 

`for team_raw in local.teams_raw : tostring(team_raw.name) => {`



`│ Error: Invalid function argument`
`│     │ local.teams_raw is tuple with 2 elements`

`│ Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert object to map of any single type`

Comment: Hmm yes... I didn't get he subteams structure quite right (missed the extra level of object with `name` and `members`) and this data structure seems a bit too complex for current Terraform to be able to figure out how to automatically convert the top-level structure to a map. I fixed both things here; this should work now.

Comment: For now I worked with two separate files, as it is easier for me to understand and manage, though I am not sure I should use `tomap()` here